# Using Launchpad "Bugs" (aka Malone) standalone - HOW?

Tags: launchpad

I'm setting up a problem tracking system for a client and I'd like to use Malone to do it.  The system has be be completely private, so I can't simply buy space on launchpad.net and ignore all the other parts of the Launchpad Suite - I need to download the software and install it elsewhere.

I've seen https://dev.launchpad.net/Getting so I know how to get hold of the software itself, so what I'm asking for here is whether anyone has experience with what I'm trying to do.  Basically I need to extract the "Malone" parts of the suite, configure and deploy them.  There don't appear to be any handy RPMs, which is a pity!

Once I've got a standalone Malone server running, there are a couple of other things I'd like to do...

The first is to make the system fault-tolerant between my client's sites, so is there a way of setting up 2 or more servers in a peer-to-peer configuration so I can create a bug report at one site and have it automatically appear on the other sites?  Note that I don't want to nominate a master site that holds a single server - I need multiple servers so the sites can operate independently if necessary.

The other thing I'd like to do is set up one Malone instance as the "upstream" to my main one, in the same way that I can set up a Bugzilla, Trac or MantisBT server as an upstream.  The Launchpad docs say a lot about setting up sync links to these other tools, but are strangely quiet about linking Malone to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no concept in the Launchpad code of turning off some of the applications.  However, you can say that particular projects do or don't use bugs, code, translations, etc.  So you could just turn off every feature but bug tracking as you create projects.  (Or, for that matter, you could add configuration options to turn them off globally and send that upstream...)

As far as running it up, see https://dev.launchpad.net/Running.

Fault tolerance in the main instance is handled by having multiple replicating PostgreSQL servers and multiple Zope app servers.  You could do that.  There is no peer-to-peer mode, though it would be good to add it eventually.  And in the specific case of syncing Launchpad with another instance of itself, again, that doesn't exist, but it would be feasible and cool to add if you want.

Comment: Thanks.  I was coming to the conclusion that de-bundling Malone was a Bad Idea, so it's nice to get confirmation of that.  On the subject of replicating PostgreSQL servers, can they be on different physical sites, connecting across the Internet?  If so, what happens when one site loses its net connection, and then changes are made on both sites?  Can the databases merge and heal when the link comes back up, or do I have to trash one replica and repopulate it from the other?

Comment: Replication for launchpad.net is done using <http://slony.info>; this could run across multiple sites and it should be able to recover from disconnections.  See <http://www.slony.info/documentation/slonyintro.html#INTRODUCTION>.